# installed allegro to use with c++ on Ubuntu. #include <allegro> says can't find file

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, allegro

used these instructions https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Ubuntu_and_Allegro_5 and all seemed to work. but in my code I've used #include  and it says "fatal error: allegro: no such file or directory". I've tried #include  etc but same problem. Really tried searching and I think it is something to do with c++ not being able to find the library in the paths it's searching but I cannot work out how to move the library into the right place... help

Comment: One problem might be that you should include e.g. `<allegro.h>`, or possibly `<allegro5/allegro.h>`. Notice the `.h` at the end of the file-name.

Comment: Also, depending on where `make install` put stuff, you may need to provide appropriate `-I<path>` arguments to your compiler (and `-L<path>` and `-l<library>` as well...)